# Get euler angles from quaternion

Tags: .net, math

I wrote little code that converts quaternion to euler angles (thanks [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Source_code_2)) and i'm getting wrong angles from it

```
public static Vector3 ToEulerAngles(Quaternion quaternion)
{
    const float piOverTwo = MathF.PI / 2;

    var angles = new Vector3();

    float sqrx = quaternion.X * quaternion.X;
    float sqry = quaternion.Y * quaternion.Y;
    float sqrz = quaternion.Z * quaternion.Z;

    angles.X = MathF.Atan2(2.0f * (quaternion.W * quaternion.X + quaternion.Y * quaternion.Z), 1.0f - 2.0f * (sqrx + sqry));
    angles.Z = MathF.Atan2(2.0f * (quaternion.W * quaternion.Z + quaternion.X * quaternion.Y), 1.0f - 2.0f * (sqry + sqrz));

    float sp = 2.0f * (quaternion.W * quaternion.Y - quaternion.Z * quaternion.X);

    angles.Y = MathF.Abs(sp) >= 1 ?
        MathF.CopySign(piOverTwo, sp) : // use 90 degrees if out of range
        MathF.Asin(sp);

    return angles;
}
```

I passed 90 degrees roll to `Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll();`, passed quaternion to my method and i got these angles - <0 0 2,0354056>

Where did i screw up?

Comment: [From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.quaternion.createfromyawpitchroll?view=net-6.0) "The roll angle, **in radians**, around the Z axis." 90 degrees in radians is `1.57079633f` https://dotnetfiddle.net/9PMdYB

Comment: big thanks. i forgot to convert deg to rad